# Is there anyway to generate doc when using sails

Tags: sails.js

After using sails to generate project and controllers. 
Is there any way to generate api doc or something like swagger to show the list of api and test on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [sails-hook-swagger-generator](https://github.com/theo4u/sails-hook-swagger-generator), which will automatically generate a swagger.json file based on your custom routes and controllers. Unfortunately it doesn't work with blueprint routes (at least for me).